# How can I create an Activity that encompasses other Activities?

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

SO.  I am starting out in WF4 and I have a design/flow question.  I created a custom code activity that takes an "in argument" and stores a result to an "out argument".  Pretty basic.  Next I use an "If" flow operator using the result of the "out argument".  All of that works great.  But my question is, can I create a custom code activity that combines these two steps together?  I looked into extending from the System.Activities.Statements.If class, but the class is sealed.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Custom Control Flow. You may find [Authoring Custom Control Flow Activities in WF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535667.aspx) article to be useful.

Comment: Some more info.  Definitely use the NativeActivitys.  That worked well.  Also, if you want to use the designer GUI you must add the attribute

`[Designer(typeof(<NAME OF DESIGER>))]`

to the class that extends the NativeActivity

Comment: A better way is to follow the pattern as I showed in the sample Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4) - Custom Activity Designer http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-9e867448